# How to transition perspective-origin specifically?

Tags: javascript, css

I can't seem to animate perspective-origin without using `all` for the `transition` property.

This code works in Safari:

```
var sceneDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("scene")[0];
sceneDiv.style.perspectiveOrigin = "100% 0%";
sceneDiv.style.transition = "all 1s";
```

This code does not:

```
var sceneDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("scene")[0];
sceneDiv.style.perspectiveOrigin = "100% 0%";
sceneDiv.style.transition = "perspective-origin 1s";
```

```js
function reset()
{
    var sceneDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("scene")[0];
    sceneDiv.style.perspectiveOrigin = "50% 50%";
    sceneDiv.style.transition = "none";
}

function transitionAll()
{
    var sceneDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("scene")[0];
    sceneDiv.style.perspectiveOrigin = "10% 50%";

    /* this works ok, but using "all" affects performance */
    sceneDiv.style.transition = "all 1s";
}

function transitionPO()
{
    var sceneDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("scene")[0];
    sceneDiv.style.perspectiveOrigin = "10% 50%";

    /* this doesn't animate the object as expected */
    sceneDiv.style.transition = "perspective-origin 1s";
}
```

```css
.scene
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #404040;

    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    -moz-perspective: 600px;
    -ms-perspective: 600px;
    -o-perspective: 600px;
    perspective: 600px;
}

.object
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #ff8000;

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1200px) rotateX(60deg);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(-1200px) rotateX(60deg);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(-1200px) rotateX(60deg);
    -o-transform: translateZ(-1200px) rotateX(60deg);
    transform: translateZ(-1200px) rotateX(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
    <div class="object"></div>
</div>

<button onclick="reset()">reset</button>
<button onclick="transitionAll()">all 1s</button>
<button onclick="transitionPO()">perspective-origin 1s</button>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bw3zrexw/)**

I'd like to avoid using `all` to improve performance. What am I doing wrong in the second set of instructions?

**EDIT**

I tried using WebKit extensions in the JavaScript. Same result.

**[JSFiddle w/ WebKit](https://jsfiddle.net/bw3zrexw/1/)**

Comment: Both works in my Chrome.? which browser are you using.?

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm using Safari. Maybe I need to use webkit properties in the JavaScript. I'll try it now.

Comment: Nah. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be a bug in Safari, where they don't map the `transition: perspective-origin 1s;` shorthand to `transition: perspective-origin-x 1s, perspective-origin-y 1s;`.

Setting clearly both of these properties does work in Safari too.
But Firefox and Chrome don't like when only these two properties are set, so you will actually need the three of them:

```
transition: perspective 1s, perspective-origin-x 1s, perspective-origin-y 1s;
```

```js
function reset()
{
    var sceneDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("scene")[0];
    sceneDiv.style.perspectiveOrigin = "50% 50%";
    sceneDiv.style.transition = "none";
}

function transitionPO()
{
    var sceneDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("scene")[0];
    sceneDiv.style.perspectiveOrigin = "10% 50%";

    /* this does animates the object as expected */
    sceneDiv.style.transition = "perspective-origin 1s, perspective-origin-x 1s, perspective-origin-y 1s";
}
```

```css
/*
removed all the vendor specifics rules
since most modern browsers don't need it anymore
*/
.scene
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #404040;
    perspective: 600px;
}

.object
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #ff8000;
    transform: translateZ(-1200px) rotateX(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
    <div class="object"></div>
</div>

<button onclick="reset()">reset</button>
<button onclick="transitionPO()">perspective-origin 1s</button>
```

Comment: Ah, yup. I didn't even know you could animate the axes separately. Good enough for me. Thanks.

Comment: @DaiBu, it doesn't seem to be supported in FF, and in chrome it is still under `-webkit-` prefix. Only Safari seems to have it built-in, but they may have released it a bit too soon.

Comment: Do you mean the individual axes aren't supported in FF or perspective-origin transitions in general? What do you propose for the most cross-browser support?

Comment: Yes I mean individual axes. The most cross-browser support is what's in the answer (you could re-add the vendor prefixes I removed in CSS part though).